# ReactNative: ref and onLayout on custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a custom Component as below. Interestingly, the `ref` isn't being setup and `onLayout` isn't being fired. These problems get resolved if I wrap `MyView` inside another `View` in the `Parent` class.

**Neither ref nor onLayout work**

```
const MyView = props => 
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
```

**Ref works here**

```
class MyView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**Sample usage**

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyView ref={c => this.myView = c} onLayout={e => console.log(e)} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is working when you wrap it on another View? I don't use ref like that, but with a specific name, but you shouldn't use it if possible. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 4):

`ref` would work only on components which is why it isn't working in the first scenario.

`onLayout` is a method of `View` and doesn't get inherited by every `Component`. Passing in a `prop` and setting it on a containing `View` would solve the problem.